# Hibernate EntityManager, how to create query for delete from table_name where user_name = something

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-mvc, entitymanager, sql-delete

i am current building an web applicationg using spring mvc hibernate.
here is the query i wanna build using EntityManager class...

```
DELETE FROM registerform WHERE owner_email = 'some_user_name'
```

so bascially here is my attamped code:

```
@PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

@Transactional
    public void removeRegisteredUser(String userName) {
        CriteriaQuery<RegisterForm> c = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery(RegisterForm.class);
        Root<RegisterForm> from = c.from(RegisterForm.class);
        c.delete(from);
        c.where(em.getCriteriaBuilder().equal(from.get("owner_email"), username));
        em.createQuery(c).executeUpdate();
}
```

so bascially, it is not working at all,, actually  `c.delete`  method isnt existing in api.... I couldnt figure out how to create delete query here,.,

please help with some code example. cheers

Comment: Please check this link for basic crud operation [link](http://fruzenshtein.com/spring-mvc-hibernate-maven-crud/) with code example.

Answer (score 3):

`public void removeRegisteredUser(String userName) {
     String hqlDelete = "delete RegisterForm where ownerEmail = :email";
     int deletedEntities = entityManager.createQuery( hqlDelete )
                            .setParameter( "email", userName )
                            .executeUpdate();`